# Customize the appearance of UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uitabbar

I want to customize the UITabBar in order to have a tab in the middle that has curved border on top and slightly greater height than the other tabs, the idea might look like this http://grazsecrets.at/ , the only difference is that it uses a logo.

Comment: This has widely been discussed on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=custom+uitabbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Tab Bar alternatives at [CocoaControls](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar&commit=Search)

Answer (score 2):

There’s a great article on how to achieve this effect with an otherwise standard UITabBar over at [iDev Recipes](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/). For an entirely customized one à la Grazsecrets, though, you’ll need to roll your own custom solution with a row of UIButtons.